# foreground services stopping after several hours

Tags: java, android, google-contacts-api, foreground-service

I have an app that uses 3 foreground services to scan and process beacons with BluetoothLeScanner. Only one of them have the code to scan them, the other two services process the scanned beacons and make some api calls. 
After several hours the foreground services stops working and the notification dissappears.

The scanning is made through ScanCallback onScanResult. The scanning is restarted every 5 minutes to avoid Android stoping scanning.

I run the foreground services with START_STICKY. I've made a broadcast receiver that restarts the service when the onDestroy() method is called.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("EntryDetectionService", "Starting Service");
        super.onCreate();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String CHANNEL_ID = "Beacon Reader";
            String CHANNEL_NAME = "Scanning Beacons";

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE).setPriority(PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .build();

            startForeground(101, notification);
        }
    }
```

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        this.getBluetoothScanner();
        mainLoopHandler.post(scan);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

```
    ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .build();

    List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
             .setManufacturerData(76, new byte[] {})
             .build();
     filters.add(filter);

     if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
         bleScanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Keep APP alive
when api>21 , you can use 
[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler?hl=en)

some devices may keep app live.

[jobScheduler android example code](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)

when **onStartJob** check the service whether survive

```
public boolean isServiceRunning(Context context, String serviceName) {
        boolean isRunning = false;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> lists = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info : lists) {
            System.out.println(info.processName);
            if (info.processName.equals(serviceName)) {
                isRunning = true;
            }
        }
        return isRunning;

    }
```