# How make a Foreground Service doens't stop after several hours

Tags: kotlin, mobile, service, android-jobscheduler

i did a Foreground Service and it's works. However after several hours running it stops working. Hours later it back to work. I need a service which keep running unstoppable, or only more unstoppable that it is now

```
class RastreioService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }


    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        startForegroundService()
        /*business rules*/
        return START_STICKY
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }


    private fun startForegroundService(){
        var notification = createNotification()
        val idService = 1
        startForeground(idService, notification)
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, RastreioService::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        val notification = Notification.Builder(this, "1")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_gps_ativo)
            .setContentTitle("Localização Sendo Acessada")
            .setContentText("A sua localização está sendo acessada")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        return notification
    }


}
```

I find a similar question:
[foreground services stopping after several hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587966/foreground-services-stopping-after-several-hours)
But I didn't understand where and how i need use the JobScheduler and if this is the unique solution